# In a systemd service file, how can you get the PID of a program started with ExecStart to use in ExecStop?

Tags: signals, systemd

I'm using openvpn and have a service to start it.  I want to shut it down gracefully by sending a SIGINT signal in ExecStop but it requires the PID obviously.

```
[Unit]
Description=openvpn service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn /etc/openvpn/newyork.ovpn
#ExecStop=/usr/bin/kill -SIGINT $PID
```

I understand that `sudo systemctl stop openvpn.service` will shut it down even without an ExecStop but I'm curious how to do it more gracefully.  The openvpn documentation suggests sending a SIGINT signal.  I also just want to know if it is possible to get the PID of the process started with ExecStart within the same service file.

Should I be using `Type=forking` and `$MAINPID` to get PID of the openvpn process?

Comment: as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* be using the systemd services that already come as part of OpenVPN 2.4 – that is, `openvpn-client@.service` for client connections and `openvpn-server@.service` for servers – and you shouldn't usually need to write your own at all.

> I understand that sudo systemctl stop openvpn.service will shut it down even without an ExecStop but I'm curious how to do it more gracefully.

The default action without ExecStop is to send SIGTERM to the main process, and any well-written service will already perform a graceful stop when it receives a SIGTERM. (This includes OpenVPN, not that there's anything in it that *needs* graceful shutdown at all, especially for a client which doesn't maintain any state.)

> The openvpn documentation suggests sending a SIGINT signal

No, it suggests sending a SIGINT *or SIGTERM.*

SIGINT is what you get from Ctrl-C in a terminal, but SIGTERM is the standard "end it gracefully" signal for services and is already what systemd (and every other init system) uses to stop a service by default. For any well-designed service, it should result in a clean stop, the same as SIGINT.

But if all you want is to send a different signal, you don't need ExecStop=; just set `KillSignal=`.

> Should I be using Type=forking and $MAINPID to get PID of the openvpn process?

For the rare other situations (e.g. for ExecReload), use `$MAINPID`. This does not actually depend on Type=forking, as systemd has to track the "main PID" for any service regardless of its type.

Although that being said, `Type=forking` *is* actually better than Type=simple in this case, as it may let systemd know when the VPN connection has been fully established, if OpenVPN can be set up to delay the "forking" until the connection is up.

Even better is `Type=notify`, which is supported by OpenVPN and allows it to explicitly notify systemd that the service is "ready". The default systemd service units that come with OpenVPN actually use Type=notify.

In all cases, systemd already tracks the main process of a service so `$MAINPID` is always known; systemd itself uses it for the default stop action.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for all of that.  "

You should be using the systemd services that already come as part of OpenVPN 2.4 – that is, openvpn-client@.service for client connections and openvpn-server@.service for servers – and you shouldn't usually need to write your own at all."  This is interesting.  I will have to learn how to use it although I don't see this service in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

Comment: Ok I successfully used openvpn's service and know how to use it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Packaged services are usually in (/usr)/lib/systemd/system. (Unless your distribution deliberately omits them...) /etc is reserved for the sysadmin.

Comment: Thanks.  I found that out after seeing it in `sudo systemctl status openvpn-client@xxxx`.  I had no idea there was a whole other directory of service files.